# Variance and Average on a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, multidimensional-array

I was reading this article  and I trying to follow their code example but I think I am missing a library.

They have this :

> First, let's create a 2D matrix with some random data. We'll use the
> System.Random class to generate pseudo-random numbers:

```
var rand = new Random();

var matrix = new double[5, 5];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        matrix = rand.NextDouble() * 100;
    }
}
```

> Now that we have our data, we can calculate the **mean** and **standard deviation**:

```
  double mean = matrix.Average();
  double stdDev = Math.Sqrt(matrix.Variance());
```

but when I tried that in C# does, I get this **compile time error**:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1061  'double[*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'Variance' and no
> accessible extension method 'Variance' accepting a first argument of type 'double[*,*]'
> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried adding

```
using System.Numerics;
```

but it did not help

Comment: Did the article happen to mention or illustrate extension methods for Variance or Average??

Comment: No the only thing is had was  System.Random

Comment: @ Mark BenningField I found this:   [StatisticFormula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.statisticformula.variance?view=netframework-4.8#system-windows-forms-datavisualization-charting-statisticformula-variance(system-string-system-boolean))  but I am not sure if this is right or the sameone they are using. what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to apply *Linq* method to 2D array `T[,]` items, you can use [OfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0) (or `Cast<T>()`) to obtain a enumeration `IEnumeration<T>`.
For instance, in your case with `Average()` you can put it as

```
using System.Linq;

...

var matrix = new double[5,5];

...

double mean = matrix
  .OfType<double>() 
  .Average();
```

Since *standard Linq* doesn't have (at least in .Net 6) `Variance` method, we should do a simple statistics. Having a sequence of `x = {x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_N}` of `N` items the variance will be

```
Var(x) = Sum(x * x) / N - Sum(x) * Sum(x) / N / N
```

In our case it can be a simple `Aggregate`:

```
// Let's compute all required statistics 
//   n  - number of items
//   s  - sum of items
//   s  - sum of items squared
// in one go with a help of Aggregate 
var stat = matrix
 .OfType<double>()
 .Aggregate((n: 0, s: 0.0, ss: 0.0), (s, a) => (s.n + 1, s.s + a, s.ss + a * a));

double stdDev = Math.Sqrt(stat.ss / stat.n - stat.s * stat.s / stat.n / stat.n);
```

In order not to deal with such constructions, you can implement *extension methods*:

```
public static partial class Array2dExtensions {
  public static double Average(this double[,] matrix) {
    if (matrix == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(matrix));

    return matrix
      .OfType<double>() 
      .Average();
  }

  public static double Variance(this double[,] matrix) {
    if (matrix == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(matrix));

     var stat = matrix
       .OfType<double>()
       .Aggregate((n: 0, s: 0.0, ss: 0.0), (s, a) => 
                  (s.n + 1, s.s + a, s.ss + a * a));

     return stat.ss / stat.n - stat.s * stat.s / stat.n / stat.n; 
  }
}
```

Having this implemented you can put it as if array has `Average` and `Variance` methods:

```
double mean = matrix.Average();
double stdDev = Math.Sqrt(matrix.Variance());
```

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychecko, I am not sure I understand what you are doing.    By data you mean Matrix right? and is  Var(x) = Sum(x * x) / N - Sum(x) * Sum(x) / N / N  pseudocode?

Comment: @Spencer: As far as I can see, you have a matrix and you want to *flatten* it and then get a *single* average and variance values. The formula for variance is a pseudocode for a sequence `x` of `x_1,...,x_N`s (we have `N` items of the sequence)

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychecko, question for you are you using this [Variance](https://www.google.com/search?q=equation+for+variance&rlz=1C1CAFC_enUS890US891&oq=equation+for+variance&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30l5j0i15i22i30l2.4902j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Spencer: what is the question, please? We usually *define* as `E((x - E(x))^2)` but we can do some math and have formula for `Sum(x)`, `Sum(x * x)` and `N`